# Pyspark code taking longer time than pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata

I am currently in the process of translating a Pandas code to PySpark code. The code involves various transformations such as group by, join, and more. However, I have encountered an issue where my PySpark code runs significantly slower than the equivalent Pandas code.

I am relatively new to PySpark and have been exploring its capabilities for the past three months. During this time, I have been comparing my PySpark code with a benchmark Pandas code. Initially, my PySpark code executed quickly as I had not called any actions, but I later learned that invoking at least one action is necessary to trigger computations.

To address this requirement, I added a .count() operation in order to observe the results, but I noticed a significant increase in execution time. I am uncertain whether this is the most efficient approach or if there are alternative methods available.

I would greatly appreciate suggestions and guidance from the community on how to invoke computations in an optimized way in PySpark. My objective is to improve the performance of my code and ensure that the computations are executed efficiently.

Here is a screenshot from delight showing memory consumption through out the application's lifetime. One weird thing, I could notice is majority of the compute is going towards shuffling the data (labelled purple in the figure).

[delight screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTBu8.png)

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: To performance tune your spark code you should first look at the execution plan. https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-execution-plan/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: some side notes -- spark isn't best for all use cases. so, you should look for the best framework based on your data size and transformations. spark is best for large data sizes where distributed processing can make a difference.

Comment: Hi @samkart,
thanks for your reply, This code is expected to work on a wide range of file sizes ranging from 30000 to 200 Million records. That being said, I believe pyspark can be a good solution in this case. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for your reply. I have tried printing the execution plan, but the code got struck there for very long time and finally an error was raised saying Java heap space, out of the memory. The file that I'm presently testing should not a big deal, it hardly has 40000 records. I don't know why this is happening, but I tried visualizing DAG for few tasks, they are pretty long and gigantic..is it something that I should bother about?

Comment: If you are dealing with big data, PySpark can be the one of the best option, much better than pandas. 
For utilizing PySpark,try to avoid shuffle operations, such as joins, and groupby as much as possible. Instead of those, use map, flatMap and use other simpler actions with small functions (udfs) to achieve your transformation.

Comment: Hi @BasirMahmood, thanks for the reply. But my particular use case involves using groupbys and joins very often in the code, since I have to aggregate data from different dataframes. Does that mean pyspark cannot be a way to go? I mean, is it going to be more time consuming than pandas in this case?